# dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)) is not working to remove black background

Tags: android, dialog

I am unable to remove black background from the custom dialog, it's working fine api below 19 and higher 19  but it's showing black background round the custom dialog in  19.

please help me regarding this here's my code.

```
Dialog dialog  = new Dialog(DAR_Activity.this);
dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
LinearLayout linearLayout  = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress, null);
dialog.setContentView(linearLayout);
ProgressBar progressBar1  = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_dialog);

dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

dialog.show();
dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```